# passing reference of a variable to a template

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to pass reference variable to a template with below code but I'm getting compiler error. Can any one figure out the reason please. Thanks.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<int &T>
class Test
{
public:
    static void do_it()
    {
        T=1;
    }
};

struct A{
    static int x;
};

int A::x=0;

int main()
{
    Test<A::x> test;
    test.do_it();
    cout<<A::x;
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

> error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '.'
>      error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
>      error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
>      fatal error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Test<A.x> test;` should be `Test<A::x> test;`

Comment: Excellent Thanks,
Any specific reason, why it allows to pass only static memeber but not normal data member?

Comment: @Raj, I guess it's because you use non-type parameter, the parameter should be known at compile time. But I am not very sure about it.